# How to display exceptions from HTTP request on Android screen

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am using a basic Flutter- based get request that is going to a RESTful server. The code  for performing this request is below:

```
Future<List<Description>> getTheInfo() async {
    List<Description> result;

    try {
      http.Response resp = await http.get(theUrl + "/home/devices");

      if(resp.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonstr = json.decode(resp.body);
        var list = jsonstr["devices"] as List;
        result = list.map<Description>((json) => Description.fromJson(json)).toList();
      }
      else {
        print('FAILURE: '+resp.statusCode.toString());
      }
    } catch(exe) {
       print('Socket Failure: '+exe.toString());
       throw CustomException("FAILURE: ",exe.toString());
    }

     return(result);
  }
```

The custom exception is something I grabbed from the Internet below:

```
class CustomException implements Exception {
  final _message;
  final _prefix;

  CustomException([this._message, this._prefix]);

  String toString() {
    return "$_prefix$_message";
  }
}
```

My problem is that while I have the ability to print to the console any failures that occur in my development environment, I have no way of seeing what happens on a device. I am seeing failures when testing on my phone that I am not seeing in my development environment.

What I would like to do is have some way of displaying exceptions that are thrown from my GET request on the screen of my emulator (in my development environment) and the screen of my actual phone (when I create an APK to test on my device). Is there some way to do this?

Comment: *"I have no way of seeing what happens on a device"* - why is it so? is it a remote device you dont have acces to?

Comment: The device (a phone) just has a production APK installed on it. It is not being run in Android Studio's development environment. It does not display the console output that print() goes to and there needs to be a means of displaying a message to the user in the event of a network failure. Flutter's HTTP library provides no clear means of doing this in the event of a SocketException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure by what you are trying to accomplish here, but there is an elegant way to display failures and exceptions on to the UI to let the user know about it. This would be a good practice as well in a production app.

What you need is [dartz](https://pub.dev/packages/dartz), dartz is a functional programming package.

With dartz you can use the `Either` type to return either a `Future<List<Description>>` or a `CustomException`

here is how it'll fit into your code.

```
Future<Either<CustomException,List<Description>>>  getTheInfo() async {
    List<Description> result;

    try {
      http.Response resp = await http.get(theUrl + "/home/devices");

      if(resp.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonstr = json.decode(resp.body);
        var list = jsonstr["devices"] as List;
        result = list.map<Description>((json) => Description.fromJson(json)).toList();

        return right(result); 
      }
      else {
        print('FAILURE: '+resp.statusCode.toString());
        
       return  left(CustomException("FAILURE: ",exe.toString()));
      }
    } catch(exe) {
       print('Socket Failure: '+exe.toString());

     return  left(CustomException("FAILURE: ",exe.toString()));
    }
  }
```

On the UI side,

```
...

   Widget build(BuildContext context) {

       FutureBuilder(
         future: getTheInfo(),
         builder: (_, AysncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.connectionState ==ConnectionStatet.waiting){
               return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
           
        snapshot.data.fold( 
          (l)=> Center(child: Text(l.message),  // CustomException message 
       ),
        (r)=>  Center(child: Text("Success"),  // r contains the List<Description>
     );    
    }
  }
...
```

Depending on Success or Failure, you can render an appropriate widget.

edit:
This should work but highly recommend switching to provider or riverpord if not BLoc

Comment: Sameer: I am using a FutureBuilder to build my UI. My call to getTheInfo() is done in my toplevel widget's initState() method. 1: will I need to declare my initState() method async in order to do the await call to getTheInfo()? What will that do to the initState() method? 2: Will I be able to safely replace my FutureBuilder (which would be a good thing, actually!)?

Comment: No, you cannot make your `initState()` async, and yes you should switch to some state management solution for better control on what you show on the screen. Let me edit my answer to show how it would work with `FutureBuilder()` but recommend switching to provider at least.

Comment: Actually, it turns out that I have no choice but to use a FutureBuilder, because the HTTP package requires that any function calling its API must be an async function, and async functions must always return futures. Consequently, the code you previously presented for the getTheInfo() function will not compile. There is no way to avoid using FutureBuilder when using info from an HTTP GET request to determine what controls you will build. That, incidentally, is what I am doing.

Comment: Umm, not quite, `FutureBuilder()` is not the only way to resolve futures, you can do it using `await` as well. If you use a state management solution like Changenotifier than you can resolve your future there and then return only the data. And what part of my code is not compiling? could you point me to it?  And [here](https://github.com/Sameerkash/TodoApp) is an example app I did,  checkout `lib/ui/todos/todo_vm.dart` where I am calling to  `localStorage` which is also `async`. This is a better way to resolve futures and handle state.